# Ember view without handlebars

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

How can I create a view in Ember that uses plain 'ol HTML rather than a handlebars template? I'm using a graphing library called Rickshaw, and I want to be able to call its "render" function, which draws to the screen, but I can't execute javascript within a handlebars template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
App.GraphView = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function () {
        var graph = new Rickshaw.Graph({
            element: this.$().get(0),
            series: [] // DATA
        }):
        graph.render();
    }
});
```

`didInsertElement` is called once the view is inserted into DOM and by calling `this.$().get(0)` you can get its base DOM element.